# How to create a WPF Window without a border that can be resized?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

Is there a way in WPF where I can remove the main window's border, yet allow that window to be resized (without grip)?

I realized there's a way to do this scenario by setting resize mode to `CanResizeWithGrip`. However, I want to be able to do it with the resize mode set to `CanResize`.

I tried setting the following:

```
ResizeMode="CanResize" 
WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
```

However, by setting `AllowsTransparency`, it removes the ability to resize without the grip. Any ideas how I can pull this off?

I also should note that I can't set `AllowsTransparency` to true anyway, because I am using a winformshost control in my window, which is not shown when `AllowsTransparency`  is true.

Comment: I decided to just revamp my UI instead, and just set ResizeMode="CanResize" and left the border in tact.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I just wanted to put up a working sample for newcomers.

Xaml Window:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomWindowDemo.DemoCustomWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomWindowDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DemoCustomWindow" Height="300" Width="300" Background="{x:Null}" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BorderThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                        <Rectangle MinWidth="4" MinHeight="4" StrokeThickness="0">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" Opacity="0.05"/>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="#55FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border MouseMove="Header_MouseMove" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="32"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,3">
                            <GradientStop Color="#3BB2EA" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#EFF7FA" Offset="0.3" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btn_Minimize" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0" Click="btn_Minimize_Click" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Image Source="Resources/Ahmadhania-Spherical-Minimize.ico"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="btn_Maximize" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" Click="btn_Maximize_Click">
                            <Image Source="Resources/1412181205_61002.ico"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="btn_Close" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="3" Click="btn_Close_Click">
                            <Image Source="Resources/Ahmadhania-Spherical-Close(1).ico"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbBottom" DragDelta="ThumbBottom_DragDelta" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="SizeNS" Grid.Column="0" Background="{x:Null}"  Margin="3,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}"/>
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbTop" DragDelta="ThumbTop_DragDelta" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="SizeNS" Grid.Column="0" Background="{x:Null}"  Margin="3,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="4" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}"/>
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbBottomRightCorner" DragDelta="ThumbBottomRightCorner_DragDelta" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Background="{x:Null}" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}"/>
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbTopRightCorner" DragDelta="ThumbTopRightCorner_DragDelta" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="SizeNESW" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="{x:Null}" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}"/>
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbTopLeftCorner" DragDelta="ThumbTopLeftCorner_DragDelta" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="SizeNWSE" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="{x:Null}" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}" />
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbBottomLeftCorner" DragDelta="ThumbBottomLeftCorner_DragDelta" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="SizeNESW" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="{x:Null}" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}" />
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbRight" DragDelta="ThumbRight_DragDelta" Cursor="SizeWE" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" Background="{x:Null}"  Margin="0,3" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}"/>
            <Thumb x:Name="ThumbLeft" DragDelta="ThumbLeft_DragDelta" Cursor="SizeWE" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,3" Style="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource BorderThumb}}"/>
            <Grid x:Name="Grid_Content" Background="#EFF7FA" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

C# code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Interop;
using winforms = System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomWindowDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DemoCustomWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DemoCustomWindow : Window
    {
        bool Maximized = false;
        int NormalWidth = 0;
        int NormalHeight = 0;
        int NormalX = 0;
        int NormalY = 0;

        public DemoCustomWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Header & Resize
        void Header_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                this.DragMove();
        }

        void ThumbBottomRightCorner_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Width + e.HorizontalChange > 10)
                this.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
            if (this.Height + e.VerticalChange > 10)
                this.Height += e.VerticalChange;
        }
        void ThumbTopRightCorner_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Width + e.HorizontalChange > 10)
                this.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
            if (this.Top + e.VerticalChange > 10)
            {
                this.Top += e.VerticalChange;
                this.Height -= e.VerticalChange;
            }
        }
        void ThumbTopLeftCorner_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Left + e.HorizontalChange > 10)
            {
                this.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
            }
            if (this.Top + e.VerticalChange > 10)
            {
                this.Top += e.VerticalChange;
                this.Height -= e.VerticalChange;
            }
        }
        void ThumbBottomLeftCorner_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Left + e.HorizontalChange > 10)
            {
                this.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
            }
            if (this.Height + e.VerticalChange > 10)
                this.Height += e.VerticalChange;
        }
        void ThumbRight_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Width + e.HorizontalChange > 10)
                this.Width += e.HorizontalChange;
        }
        void ThumbLeft_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Left + e.HorizontalChange > 10)
            {
                this.Left += e.HorizontalChange;
                this.Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
            }
        }
        void ThumbBottom_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Height + e.VerticalChange > 10)
                this.Height += e.VerticalChange;
        }
        void ThumbTop_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Top + e.VerticalChange > 10)
            {
                this.Top += e.VerticalChange;
                this.Height -= e.VerticalChange;
            }
        }

        void btn_Minimize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
        void btn_Maximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Maximized == true)
            {
                this.Width = NormalWidth;
                this.Height = NormalHeight;
                this.Left = NormalX;
                this.Top = NormalY;
                Maximized = false;
                Thumbs();
            }
            else
            {
                NormalX = (int)this.Left;
                NormalY = (int)this.Top;
                NormalHeight = (int)this.Height;
                NormalWidth = (int)this.Width;
                this.Left = winforms.Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).WorkingArea.Left;
                this.Top = winforms.Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).WorkingArea.Top;
                this.Width = winforms.Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).WorkingArea.Width;
                this.Height = winforms.Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle).WorkingArea.Height;
                Maximized = true;
                Thumbs();
            }
        }
        void btn_Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
        void Thumbs()
        {
            if (Maximized == true)
            {
                ThumbBottom.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbLeft.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbTop.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbRight.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbTopLeftCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbTopRightCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbBottomLeftCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ThumbBottomRightCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                ThumbBottom.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbLeft.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbTop.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbRight.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbTopLeftCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbTopRightCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbBottomLeftCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ThumbBottomRightCorner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember, there is a property Window.RestoreBounds which represents exactly the size that window will get back to after transition to normal state

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if `ResizeBorderThickness` is set to 0.

It can be set to a positive value in XAML like this:

```
<WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness>
        <Thickness>1</Thickness>
    </WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness>
</WindowChrome>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WPF customizable window library, available here: http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/

Then, when using the library's window type, you can set the same properties as you listed above

```
<CustomWindow:EssentialWindow x:Class="CustomWindowDemo.DemoEssentialWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:CustomWindow="clr-namespace:CustomWindow;assembly=CustomWindow"
    AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStyle="None" Title="EssentialWindow"
    Height="300" Width="250">
```

Comment: On their site, it says:  Complete customization of WPF window can be done only when AllowsTransparency is set to "True".

Again, unfortunately I cannot use that due to the WinFormsHost bug, where the control is not displayed when AllowsTransparency is set to true. Maybe if I can get past that issue, your response would be a close to ideal solution.

Comment: @jsirr13, I haven't tried it, but here's a solution on how to solve the WinFormsHost bug http://mrtncls.blogspot.com/2011/07/windowsformshost-on-transparent-wpf.html also solution via Win API http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/646970-c%23-wpf-window-with-transparency-makes-windowsformshost-disappear/

Comment: I tried the second solution, no luck. I'll try the first solution when I have time. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The user needs something to interact with to resize the window.  If you don't like the default border or grip, you'll need to add some other control with a click and drag behavior that resizes the window.  Perhaps a line on each edge of the window?

Answer (score -5):

The simplest, but maybe too simple is

```
this.MouseLeftButtonDown += delegate { this.DragMove(); };
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to move the window, but merely resize when the border (which I ultimately just want hidden) is dragged. ESsentially I want to emulate the generally behavior of resizing a window, just with the border hidden.

Comment: Then you'll need to capture the edge you're moving and adjust the X,Y,W,H depending on the edge.